# jQuery Post Success

Tags: jquery

Hey everbody, im getting some trouble here.

When span gets clicked, it sends to a php some data, deleteing from my MySQL something. OK!
This is fine. Working.

But, when i try to set to jquery hide or fade out a element for me, inside the post action, he doesnt hides it.

But when i set it out of POST action, it works.  Why?

```
$('.deletar span').click(function() {
    //alert($(this).attr('id'));
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $(this).parent().parent().find('.carregando').show();

    $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut();


    /*$.post('deletar.php',{id: id}, function(data){
            //$(this).parent().parent().find('.carregando').hide();
                //$.parent().parent().parent().text('haha');
                alert($(this).parent().parent().find('.carregando'));
                $(this).parent().parent().find('.carregando').fadeOut();
    });*/




});
```

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure the POST is successful? It sounds like it isn't...better look in Firebug/your tool of choice and see what's coming back.

Comment: May be the post function can't be treated like click or mouseover, (I've never used it as an event function)

Comment: In the callback from POST, `$(this)` is NOT the element clicked on.  You need to save a reference to `$(this)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be a scope thing. Try:

```
var $that = $(this);
$.post('deletar.php',{id: id}, function(data){
    $that.parent().parent().find('.carregando').hide();
});
```